# Set Textbox to "00:00:00" format

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating a userform that will show the value of a specific cell in the "Timer" sheet into the textbox1 in my userform. The cell contains time. However, whenever I try to run the userform the textbox won't show the value of the cell in `"00:00:00"` format.

Please check the codes I'm working on below:

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Timer")
    sh.Range("R1").Value = "Start"

    If sh.Range("R2").Value = "" Then
        sh.Range("R2").Value = Now
    End If

x:
    VBA.DoEvents

    If sh.Range("R1").Value = "Stop" Then Exit Sub

    sh.Range("R3").Value = Now
    Me.TextBox1.Value = sh.Range("R4").Value

GoTo x

End Sub
```

I already tried adding: `Textbox1.value = Format("00:00:00")` in the VBA, but it is not working. It tends to show the value of `textbox1` as `"12:00:00 AM"`

Comment: Try `HH:MM:SS`.  depending on the data you're giving it, it should still work properly in "timer" format.  Actually, what value ARE you giving it?  is this like a countdiwn timer? or you want it to show actual time but only sometimes?  more info required!

Comment: Change your "Me.TextBox1" line to `MeTextBox1.Value = sh.Format(Range("R4").Value, "HH:MM:SS")` should fix it